# How to define two models for different binds with the same tablename

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using multiple databases (`db_1` and `db_2`) with binds in Flask:

`config.py`

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'db_1-postgres-url'
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'historic': 'db_2-postgres-url',
}
```

But when I define the models for my already existing databases (tables `db_1.mytable` and `db_2.mytable`)

```
class Model1(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'

class Model2(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    __bind_key__ = 'historic'
```

it fails with the following error:

```
InvalidRequestError: Table 'mytable' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.
File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
File "myproject/run.py", line 56, in create_app
File "/myproject/views.py", line 9, in <module>
File "/myproject/historic_models.py", line 59, in <module> 
File "flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 609, in __init__
File "sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/api.py", line 55, in __init__
File "sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 88, in _as_declarative
File "sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 103, in setup_mapping
File "sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 131, in __init__
File "sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 394, in _setup_table
File "sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 398, in __new__
```

I tried to define them using different base clases: one using `flask-sqlalchemy` and the other using `declarative_base`:

```
class Model1(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_BINDS.get('historic'))
Base.metadata.bind = engine

class Model2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    __bind_key__ = 'historic'
```

In this case I can run my application without errors, but when I write a query for `Model2`, it still consults `db_1.mytable` instead of `db_2.mytable`.

I tried the solution from [this pull request](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/222/files), and it worked, but since it's not in Flask-SQLAlchemy yet is there a way to accomplish the same thing?